# SQL - Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to set a variable to the return value of a select statement by doing:

```
declare @Owner int = 0;

set @Owner = (select distinct [TodoTitle].[owner], TodoTitle.id 
              from TodoTitle
              join todoTree on TodoTitle.id = todoTree.todoid
              where todoid = @todoId);
```

I keep getting this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Any help would be appreciated,

Mark

Comment: You are trying to assign two columns to one variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subquery must have only one column in result set:

```
set @Owner = (select distinct [TodoTitle].[owner] from TodoTitle
      join todoTree on TodoTitle.id = todoTree.todoid
      where todoid = @todoId);
```

Also subquery must have only one row in result set, I'm not sure that your `distinct` will provide this. Maybe you will get this error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: @MarkMoonieGriffiths, glad to help you

Answer (score 3):

What do you not understand about the error message?  Your subquery has two columns.  You can easily fix that by removing one of them:

```
set @Owner = (select distinct [TodoTitle].[owner]
              from TodoTitle join
                   todoTree
                   on TodoTitle.id = todoTree.todoid
              where todoid = @todoId
             );
```

However, this subquery is probably returning more than one row -- and a scalar variable can have only one value. You can easily fix that syntax problem with `top 1`:

```
set @Owner = (select top 1 [TodoTitle].[owner], TodoTitle.id 
              from TodoTitle join
                   todoTree
                   on TodoTitle.id = todoTree.todoid
              where todoid = @todoId
             );
```

I would guess that you don't really know what you are doing.  You should ask *another* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.  The SQL that you have started is not particularly useful.

Comment: For multiple rows in subquery another error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: Using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read multiple columns with one select you can write your query like this. But your query should return only one row, that's why you have to use `top 1`.

```
declare @Owner int = 0;
declare @id int;

select top 1 @Owner = [TodoTitle].[owner], @id = TodoTitle.id 
from TodoTitle
join todoTree on TodoTitle.id = todoTree.todoid
where todoid = @todoId;
```